# Rails: Nesting resources more than 1 level deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app, Users have many Conversations, and Conversations have many Messages. I logically structured my resources as follows:

```
  resources :users do
    resources :conversations do
      resources :messages
    end
  end
```

To me, this is a logical structure. But it is advised to never nest resources more than 1 level deep.

So, should I make Conversations an independent resource or just go ahead and break the guideline? What are the global advantages and drawbacks of each approach?

Thanks.

Comment: accept answers  from your previous questions. but it seems you already did so good job :)

Answer (score 5):

> But it is advised to never nest resources more than 1 level deep.

I think you can safely disregard that "advice". You can nest them as much as you want. I frequently nest 3 and 4 levels deep in my apps.

Comment: do you have an example for a 3 or 4 times nested resource? just wondering what the urls look like (and if they're still readable)!

Comment: `/apps/4/app_languages/15/localized_string_translation/edit` is an example.

Comment: /groups/1/users/2/evaluations is a nice example I've used.

Answer (score 0):

the only advice is what the meet business requirements. if you need to have 2 deep level, just try how it works with using **:shallow=>true**. but sure, it's rarely to use more than 1 deep level on practice