# Right way to handle deeply nested resources in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested-resources

So I have four models, A, B, C, and D that I associate with has_many and belong_to. I want to have a nested route formation for D.

D belongs_to A, B and C and there is no case that it can be otherwise. However when creating a nested resource for this route I am doing:

```
resources :A do
  resources :B do
    resources :C do
      resources :D 
    end
  end
end
```

Now this creates the url I want, but I don't need any of the resources from B and C creating under this formation. So I will never have a new_A_B_path call anywhere in my code. All I want is to know A, B and C when I'm creating or editing a new D.

What is the right way to handle this?

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/q/6722900/684934 . You should be aware that deep nesting is advised against, simply because it makes URIs and helper method names and argument lists long.

Comment: thanks for guiding me there. so what I understand there is, it's not that big a deal unless the url is still readable